# Insert Text Into an HTML Style Tag - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, innerhtml

I have some CSS text in an HTML `code` tag that I would like to inject into a `<style>` tag on a page.

I can isolate the text content, but it doesn't seem to allow me to put this text content into the style tag using `.textContent` - is it not possible to do this on a style tag in JavaScript?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/YzydmGb

```js
// GET TEXT CONTENT OF CODE TAG
var CSSInner = document.getElementById("language-css-js").textContent;

// INJECT TEXT CONTENT BETWEEN STYLE TAGS
function resultInsertCSS() {
  document.getElementById("result-pane-style-tag").textContent = CSSInner;
}

resultInsertCSS();
```

```html
<code id="language-css-js">
  h2 {
  line-height: 1.2;
  }
  p {
  line-height: 1.5;
  }
</code>

<style id="#result-pane-style-tag"></style>
```

Comment: The # is not necessary bro

Comment: Does it need to be in a style tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can do that. It would probably be better to assign the style directly, but if you just want to do it how you've described, here is a working example.

https://repl.it/@nicholashazel/ExpertSpecializedStructs

```
<code id="language-css-js">
  h2 {
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: red;
  }
</code>

<style id="result-pane-style-tag"></style>
<h2>Hello</h2>
<script>
  let stuff = document.getElementById('language-css-js').innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('result-pane-style-tag').textContent = stuff;
</script>
```

Also, as mentioned in the other answers, the fact that it is an ID inherently gives it the `#` property, so adding that to the ID isn't relevant.

The ID should be `result-pane-style-tag`
Referencing the ID in CSS or with jQuery, you'd use `#result-pane-style-tag`, but with the `getElementById` you would just reference it as its named.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style id="#result-pane-style-tag"></style>
```

should be

```
<style id="result-pane-style-tag"></style>
```

without the #.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the # before the id and the following code should work:

```
// GET TEXT CONTENT OF CODE TAG
var CSSInner = document.getElementById("language-css-js").innerHTML;

// INJECT TEXT CONTENT BETWEEN STYLE TAGS
function resultInsertCSS() {
  document.getElementById("result-pane-style-tag").textContent = CSSInner;
  document.getElementById("language-css-js").innerHTML=""
}

resultInsertCSS();
```